# How to fetch the php variable value inside javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

i am trying to fetch the php variable value inside the javascript. 
i am using this syntax to fetch the php variable to fetch in javacript.

but when i call the javascript function(), its displaying nothing.

javscript code

```
function cali()
{
    var lat = '<?php echo $row['lat']; ?>';
    var lon = '<?php echo $row['lon']; ?>';
    alert(lat); 
    alert(lon);
}
```

This is the php code. here i want to fetch the $row['lat'] and $row['lat'] to javascript function()

PHP code

```
 <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mande", "mande") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("theaterdb") or die(mysql_error());
$strSQL =("SELECT theater_name,address,lat,lon FROM theaters WHERE theater_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course']) . "'");
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo "<b>Theater Name:</b><br>";
echo $row['theater_name'] . "<br /><br />";
echo "<b>Theater Address:</b><br>";
echo $row['address'] . "<br /><br />";
echo "<b>Latitude:</b><br>";
echo $row['lat'] . "<br />";
echo "<b>Longitude:</b><br>";
echo $row['lon'] . "<br /><br />";
 }
 mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: try this var `lat = '<?php echo $row["lat"]; ?>';`

Comment: I tried in both the ways, its still showing no values in alert :(

Comment: Check the scope of your php variable. It should be in the scope while using in the javascript function. The syntax you have used is correct.

Comment: Perhaps the php variable does not exist while you are adding it to js variable. Use firebug to catch errors, if there is undefined error im right.

Comment: Where is this code? in a PHP? a Javascript?

Comment: Is the the JS code inside of a PHP file? When you see the JS code the browser received (looked at the page document source) do you see `var lat = 'lat value'`?

Comment: Share the whole of your PHP code.

Comment: the php you shared doesn't help. like suggested by others. Share the whole of the code.

Comment: I have shared my whole php code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function cali()
{
    var lat = "<?php echo $row['lat']; ?>";
    var lon = "<?php echo $row['lon']; ?>";
    alert(lat); 
    alert(lon);
}

//if jquery
//include jquery.js here
$(document).ready(function(){
 cali();
});

//if simple/core javascript
<body onload="cali();">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to page onload alert please use jquery
Use this function within document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function cali()
{
    var lat = '<?php echo $row['lat']; ?>';
    var lon = '<?php echo $row['lon']; ?>';
    alert(lat); 
    alert(lon);
}
});
```

Else you are not call the function

```
function cali()
{
    var lat = '<?php echo $row['lat']; ?>';
    var lon = '<?php echo $row['lon']; ?>';
    alert(lat); 
    alert(lon);
}
```

please call above within javascript

```
cail()
```

Still now you are unable to show your result. please check your php code

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do that and the question mentions nothing about jQuery. Instead, use the body onload attribute i.e. <body onload="cali()">.

Answer (score 0):

here at this point there are several things you must notice and take care of.

1. If you are passing php variable then **it will only work if the value has been submitted to the server once**. ***but as javascript is client side and run on browser itself so it can run as soon as the page is loaded***.
2. Even if you are fetching those variables in the javascript its **not called the function  within while loop**. OR call it using jquery on **document.ready function** .

hope now it wld help u. :)